# if else statement with loop in while loop/php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I will admit right now I have gone through all of the posts though I went through to 2008. My problem is that the if else statement is only receiving one row and calling all the others false off of both of the while loops or receives 2 when you use the form. I am trying to see if in all the rows if a item is bought using 2 different databases. Here is the code.

```
$id2 = $_SESSION['id'];
$naturesql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM backgrounds WHERE type=2");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($naturesql)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $background = $row['background'];
    $pic = $row['image'];

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store_items WHERE userid='$id2'");
    while($checkrow = mysql_fetch_array($check)) {
        $types = $checkrow['type2'];
    }

    if($id == $types) {
        $bought = 'This item has already been bought';
    } else {
        $bought = '<form>
                   </form>';
    // this form works fine
    }

    $display .= '<table width="100%"><tr><td><center><font size="+1">' . $name . '</font></center></td></tr><tr><td><center><img src="' . $pic . '" width="80px"></img></center></td></tr><tr><td>' . $bought . ' </td></tr></table>';
}

...

<?php echo $display ?>
```

What shows up.

> 1st result
> Name 1
> Pic 1
> form shows up here
>
> 2nd result
> Name 2
> Pic 2
> form also shows up here
>
> 3rd and last result
> Name 3
> Pic 3
> This item has already been bought

This is what I get when I look on the page. If I bought a item this is what I get lets say 1st item.

> 1st result
> Name 1
> Pic 1
> This item has already been bought
>
> 2nd result
> Name 2
> Pic 2
> form also shows up here
>
> 3rd and last result
> Name 3
> Pic 3
> This item has already been bought

It pops this up. Though when I refresh turns back into the the 1st one I shown only showing 1 result. Any thoughts why not working with the others.

It should be like this if you bought all but is not

> 1st result
> Name 1
> Pic 1
> This item has already been bought
>
> 2nd result
> Name 2
> Pic 2
> This item has already been bought
>
> 3rd and last result
> Name 3
> Pic 3
> This item has already been bought

My only other question is there an alternative to this so keeps the loop and checks if the statement is true or not like a if else statement. If I can't do it with if else statement.

Comment: There's no opening quotation mark in `$bought = <form>`, just so you know. [Here's a full reformat.](http://codepad.org/dXKlrLtv)

Comment: minitech, seems like a copy&paste issue

Comment: @Richard: I know, I was going to edit it and just point it out (in case it did matter) but instead I just did a big cleanup so it took a while.

Comment: Your code is not valid php. I tidied it up as well as I could, but there is no way that actually works.

Comment: I made this coding my self so its not copy paste issue. The form part is fine. I will edit that back. I removed all the almost all the form for security reasons.

Comment: @Chris: Why is there no way it actually works? Looks valid enough (syntactically, that is) to me.

Comment: Yes it works and its php. I can get everything but the if else statement to work properly.

Comment: Well now it might. I'm talking about my version which was apparently wiped out.

Comment: That still leaves the issue what the if else statement doesn't loop with both loops. Which isn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I get worried when I see PHP code not using [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. I hope your `$_SESSION['id']` is set to something sanitary in code not shown here. If not, please consider re-writing the code to use PDO Prepared Statements.

Comment: its all fine I have all my coding secure I just doesn't post everything for that exact reason.

Comment: @sarnold thats why noones answered & just argued in the comments box, as fear of the downvoters just because of the dreaded mysql_* functions

Comment: I am still working on the problem myself. If I do end up figuring out an answer and no one else has I will post an answer on here and answer my own question and help others that run into this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't post everything on here though here should give some in site what I did to get this to work. Surprisingly it worked like a charm. Note to everyone putting in 2 tables in one mysql_query didn't help at all it just made things worse. So I wouldn't advise it for this.

Simple version I did

```
$id = $_SESSION[id];

      $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store_items WHERE userid='$id2'");
while($checkrow = mysql_fetch_array($check)){

$types = $checkrow['type2'];



}


    $naturesql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM backgrounds WHERE type=2");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($naturesql)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $background = $row['background'];
    $pic = $row['image'];


$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store_items WHERE userid='$id2' AND type=2 AND type2='$id' AND other='$pic'");
while($checkrow = mysql_fetch_array($check)) {
    $types = $checkrow['type2'];

}
if($id == $types) {
    $bought = 'This item has already been bought';
} else {
    $bought = '<form>
               </form>';
// this form works fine
}


$display .= '<table width="100%"><tr><td><center><font size="+1">' . $name . '</font></center></td></tr><tr><td><center><img src="' . $pic . '" width="80px"></img></center></td></tr><tr><td>' . $bought . ' </td></tr></table>';

}
```

Like I promised I would post if I figured it out. Might of toke a little longer then I hoped but well there you go.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can summarize this in 1 query (it's not in 2 database, but in 2 tables it seems from your code)

```
   SELECT b.*, s.type2 AS store_items_type2
     FROM backgrounds AS b
LEFT JOIN store_items AS s ON (s.type2 = b.id AND s.userid='$id2')
    WHERE b.type=2
```

How come `$id2 = $_SESSION['id'];`? A session ID is not the same as a user ID..

You should try to put a little more effort in constructing your question and the code, to make it more understandable for us.

Comment: Sadly that is not as true as you think. $_SESSION['id'] can equal a user id you just need to know how to do it.